# How to remove all records from LDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

Is it possible to remove all entries from LDAP by one-line commend?

I tried:

```
ldapdelete -r 'cn=*,dc=domain,dc=com' -w
```

but it's not working. I have no better ideas;/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ldapdelete` is to remove specific DN, you can't use a wilcard.

There is no native "oneliner". You can execute a `ldapsearch` and provide the list of DN resulting from this search to the `ldapdelete`

Something like :

```
ldapsearch -LLL -s one -b "dc=domain,dc=com" "(cn=*)" dn | awk -F": " '$1~/^\s*dn/{print $2}' > listOfDNtoRemove.txt && ldapdelete -r -f listOfDNtoRemove.txt
```

- `-s one` : this option on the `ldapsearch` is to retrieve only the first level child under the branch `dc=domain,dc=com`
- `-LLL` : this option is to have `LDIF` format output
- `-r` : this option is to recursively delete the previously first level branch found and their childs
- `awk -F": " '$1~/^\s*dn/{print $2}'` : this `awk` is to print only the line starting by `dn:` and printing the value of the `dn`

NOTE : `ldapdelete` also reads the list of DN from the standard input, so you can pipe the `ldapsearch` results directly to the `ldapdelete` if you want to avoid the temporary file

Answer (score 1):

### With the HDB backend

You can try this approach: go to the `/var/lib/ldap` directory and run this command:

```
sudo rm __db.* *.bdb log.*
```

The `slapd` server should preferably be shutdown before running this command.

**Make sure you have a backup of the files before executing this**

### With the MDB backend

Similar as the above, but the file names are different:

```
sudo rm *.mdb
```