# ldapdelete: invalid option -- 'r'

Tags: recursion, ldap, ldif

I have a problem in the execution of the recursive ldapdelete -r command, when I connect to an ldap virtual machine that I have as root and execute the command `ldapdelete -r -h ip -p 389 -D "cn=admin,o=ms,c=fr" -w Ap201 -f /tmp/ldapContextes >> $reportFile 2>> $errorFile`, it deletes all the entries in the ldap but if I connect with another bousr user and launch the same command I get the following error : `ldapdelete: invalid option -- 'r'`

I have thought that it is a problem of permissions for the boeusr user but when entering the binaries I have seen that ldapdelete has execution permissions for root, group and other users which means that boeusr has execution permissions but I don't understand why I get the message of mistake. anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `-r` option in `ldapdelete`, you can't recursively delete entries in ldap with this command.

You have to specify each `dn` you want to remove one by one, and in the correct order (ie. you can't remove an entry which contains children).

Check the solution I provided to the same kind of question here : [How to remove all records from LDAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161477/how-to-remove-all-records-from-ldap/45162969#45162969)